# Reshaping vector to n-d matrix in row-wise order

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

I'm trying to convert a vector into a 3d matrix in a row-wise manner.

For example, my vector is:

```
a = 1:18;
```

and I'd like to convert this to a 2x3x3 matrix:

```
 b(:,:,1) = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
 b(:,:,2) = [7 8 9; 10 11 12];
 b(:,:,3) = [13 14 15; 16 17 18];
```

but the reshape function (i.e. `reshape(a, 2,3,3)`) arranges the elements in a column-wise fashion as:

```
val(:,:,1) =

     1     3     5
     2     4     6


val(:,:,2) =

     7     9    11
     8    10    12


val(:,:,3) =

    13    15    17
    14    16    18
```

How can I obtain the matrix b from vector a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use combination of [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) and [`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html).

```
b = permute(reshape(a,3,2,3),[2 1 3]);
```

```
b(:,:,1) =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6


b(:,:,2) =

     7     8     9
    10    11    12


b(:,:,3) =

    13    14    15
    16    17    18
```

Comment: Thanks! That's easier than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a (or the) solution:

```
b = permute(reshape(reshape(a,3,[])',2,3,[]), [1,3,2])

b(:,:,1) =

 1     2     3
 4     5     6


b(:,:,2) =

     7     8     9
    10    11    12


b(:,:,3) =

    13    14    15
    16    17    18
```